# How do I access the array of label values?

Tags: views, theming

I can access the value of fields in my template using `$view->style_plugin->rendered_fields`.

How do I access the array of label values in my template file?

```
$datas = $view->style_plugin->rendered_fields;
print_r($datas);

// Response
// Array ( [0] => Array ( [field_company_name] => Google [field_registered_address] => USA ) )
```

Comment: What leads you to believe such an array exists? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Logged this question since I couldn't find any documentation.  Reason to believe is, if field values can be accessed, why not the label?

Comment: Doesn't `rendered_fields` contain the label as well? It hink that's the point - it's already rendered by the time you get to that template file

Comment: No it doesn't have it, I double checked.

Comment: So `rendered_fields` contains one row of HTML after the other, with no labels in it, even though you've set the labels to show through the UI? That's quite strange. I think adding the code from your template file to the question would be useful

Comment: Clive, I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks - what's the name of the template you're overriding?

Comment: It's views-view-unformatted--mini-shop--block-1.tpl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field definitions are in a slightly different place, you can extract all labels with something like this:

```
$labels = array();
foreach ($view->display['NAME_OF_DISPLAY']->display_options['fields'] as $definition) {
  $labels[] = empty($definition['label']) ? 'No label' : $definition['label'];
}
```

Comment: good, it works.